# Creating a custom spell with elemental damage and elemental weakness

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I want to make a custom spell in Elder Scrolls Oblivion with this properties:

```
Vampire Killer
Fire Damage X points for Y seconds on Target
Weakness to Fire X percent for Y seconds on Target
```

How should I combine the duration of elemental damage and elemental weakness in order to create an effective spell? Thanks in advance

Comment: Voting to reopen because creating a spell is an in-game mechanic of Oblivion, and this has nothing to do with "game design and development". The question may be slightly opinion-based but could be easily rephrased to ask what combination of Fire Damage and Weakness to Fire will give the most damage-per-cast.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I'm gonna guess those who voted to close didn't know it was an in-game mechanic, and assumed it was mod related. I wouldn't have known either without your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the wiki](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Weakness_to_Fire), weakness to fire will not boost the damage from fire spells when the effects are in the same spell. I believe this also means even if duration is added to the spells. So the recommendation for maximum damage would be two spells, one that weakens to fire (and possibly weakness to magic as well which will boost the fire spell's damage multiplied by the fire weakness) and then a spell to do the damage.

Depending on your Magika, or how often you want to be able to cast this spell combo, you could set the duration of the weakness to a short amount, long enough to switch spells and cast the actual damage spell, or perhaps increase duration and make it so you can also increase the duration of the damage spell. For the latter, you'll have to determine how long in seconds​ it takes you personally to switch spells and cast in order to optimize the ratio of damage to duration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @prijatelj, too bad I can't boost fire damage with fire weakness.